# Time Complexity Analysis of Multistage Graph using Bottom Up Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

Time complexity of Multistage Graph is O(n^2) or O(v^2) but then some people says it's O(E). So, from O(V^2) to O(E) are they taking about dense/complete graphs in which number of edges |E| = |V^2|?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-stage graph algorithm for shortest path, we minimise cost for every *edge* exactly once. So the Time Complexity is `O(E)`. 
However, in the worst case, we get a complete graph, which has edges `E = n*(n-1)/2`, so worst time complexity then becomes `O(E) = O(n^2)`.

Note that in this case too, every edge is processed exactly once.

Comment: So, we should go with O(E) or O(V^2)?

Comment: @Geeklovenerds Go with O(E).